# Switch between Playable assets in ONE Scene at Runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, timeline

I'm struggling on how to switch between playable assets at runtime in one scene using timeline.

What I want to do is something like this

I have a scene and have Playable Direction component attached to the gameObject "TimelineManager".

When I press <kbd>Space</kbd> it will play playableAsset A, or press <kbd>Return</kbd> it will play playableAsset B.

I'm aware I can dynamically switch playable assets by code something like

`director.Play(plyableAssetA) or director.Play(playableAssetB)`

What I'm struggling is that I want to load whatever playableAsset and gameObjects linked to and set it to PlayableDirector at runtime, but I've noticed that if you switch between plyableAssets, you lose all the gameObjects references.

Do I have to make multiple scenes and have PlayableDirector at each scene?

I tried googling, Youtubeing, all the stuff I can try.

Comment: No, just on swapping you have to refind the items

Comment: thx for the comment. i managed to figure out myself how to dynamically set objects on clips' reference assets. :)